# How to use kafka-avro-console-producer ?

Tags: properties, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, producer

If I use 'kafka-console-producer' - it automatically picks up JASS file and runs normally (can produce to a remote topic).

If I use 'kafka-avro-console-producer' with exact same configuration but with added schema property - it complains about JASS configuration:

```
'Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set'
```

How to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into these blogs, you will know that how can you update your security and how can you add property to procedure.

[Authentication using SASL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/sasl.html)

[secure-kafka-java-producer-with-kerberos](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/02/21/secure-kafka-java-producer-with-kerberos/)